# WordPress: trying to upload image, the media_handle_upload() won't work

Tags: php, image, wordpress, forms, file-upload

Trying to make a form to upload an image to Wordpress, then set that image as a post's thumbnail. But I can't seem to get the media_handle_upload() function to work properly.

the form's input for the file

```
 <input type="file" name="image" />
```

then this is the server side code

```
media_handle_upload( $_FILES['image'], 22 );
```

and this is what I get returned

```
object(WP_Error)#212 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["upload_error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(212) "File is empty...." } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

I have played around with a couple different ways to enter the file variable,but none seems to work, am I doing that from, what exactly is the $file_id;

Comment: Have you added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form? If not then the `$_FILES` array will be empty. You could also try dumping the content of your `$_FILES` array and see so its really contains data.

Comment: Yes I have , and If I use var_dump($_FILES['image']); I get all the file information

Comment: If I look at the description for `media_handle_upload()` then it looks like you're passing incorrect arguments? The first one should be an index into `$_FILES` of the uploaded file. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload

Comment: yea, I'm trying to figure out how to correctly pass the file. I checked their doc, but i can't seem to find out how to pass it

Comment: media_handle_upload( xxxx , 22 );

Comment: No, I checked the source, you should use it like this: `media_handle_upload('image', 22);` the name of your index in the `$_FILES` array and the `post_id`

Comment: OH!!!! gotcha lol, well I feel dumb now lol. Ok I understand now, post that as an answer and I'll make it the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at [`documentation`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/) for `media_handle_upload()`, the first parameter should be the name of the index for the file in the `$_FILES` array, so in your case it should look like this:

```
media_handle_upload('image', 22);
```